# German quotation marks " followed by vowel are not treated as such

Tags: quoting, german

I want to spell `"Operational Technology"` in LaTeX. However whenever I write `"` followed bt `O`, it forms `Ö`. E.g., `Öperational Technology`.

Escaping the `o` or the `"` does not bring about the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether you employ the `babel` package and, if so, which language settings you use.

Comment: I am using `\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}` , and also `\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're employing the [babel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package with the option `ngerman`, I suggest you also load the [csquotes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package with the option `german=quotes`. That way, you can write

```
\enquote{Operational Technology}
```

to get Gänsefüßchen-style typographic opening and closing quotation marks.

Alternatively, if you wanted to output "straight", i.e., vertical, opening and closing double-quote marks, you could input

```
"{}Operational Technology"
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- needed if you use csquotes with "german=guillemets"
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes} % or: german=guillemets

\begin{document}
\enquote{Operational Technology}

"{}Operational Technology"
\end{document}
```

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Thanks for the edit.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Thank you, great: `\enquote{Operational Technology` solves the problem!

Comment: @CappiCapnalov so you should accept the answer: click on the "ok check" symbol ✅ under the voting arrows to turn it green.

Comment: @Rmano Thank you for pointing this function out to me. Checked!